# Is it demeaning to say "There is life in the old dog"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have an old member in my team. Usually we do not expect any interesting idea to come from him. But one day, he made a very useful and interesting remark. This prompted one of my friends to quip, "There is life in the old dog." The comment was made in good jest and everyone in the team including the oldie laughed it off.

Is it possible that this remark could have been incendiary at some other time? I mean, does this phrase or saying carry a sense of ill-will in it?

Comment: Sultan, I have no reference, but I think "dog" can have a positive connotation when it is called by a word like "life" in the same sentence.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I see. 'Dog' is also a very contemptible term in many languages incl. English.

Comment: You might also be careful using/writing "oldie" in reference to people. It may offend someone.

Comment: In my experience this expression is most commonly used by people in reference to themselves. When used about someone else it normally *is* intended affectionately, but offence may be taken by people who don't like to think of themselves as old. It's a somewhat back-handed compliment in that it is essentially saying "I'm impressed that someone your age can still do that, I didn't imagine you could."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This phrase (or, more completely, “There is life in the old dog *yet*”) usually isn't offensive or incendiary, but almost any words can be made so via a rude or inflammatory tone of voice.   There might also be a higher risk of offense being taken if the object of the remark is a woman rather than a man, or if it is said to someone who is sensitive about their age.  But in general it can be offered and taken as a compliment.

Comment: See comment by barrie england, it is more complicated. If someone is sensitive about being older than the others in their group, it could be taken as offensive.

Comment: @neuronet, you may find it instructive to read what I wrote:  “There might also be a higher risk of offense being taken ... if it is said to someone who is sensitive about their age”.

Comment: I should have been more precise I disagree with your overall point that in general it "can be offered and taken as a compliment" and "usually isn't offensive." It is a risky thing to say. It is one of those things where the subtleties involved might preclude its use in those who are unsure. And not only b/c the person might be sensitive about age, but because it can come off as presumptuous and insulting.

Comment: It _is_ risky unless everyone involved knows each other well, and you're sure they'll enjoy it and laugh it off. If you said that to someone in Saudi Arabia, you might lose your head -- to be compared to a filthy mongrel is an extreme offense.

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the situation, the relationships between the speakers and the personality of the old dog. In the case you mention, it turned out well, but if there's any doubt about the suitability of the expression, the best advice is not to use it.

Comment: I agree with what Barrie says. Funny as it may sound, if any of my younger co-workers said that about me, I'd regard it as a term of "affection," and take it as a compliment – particularly if they said it with me in the room, showing they weren't embarrassed and had nothing to hide. After familiarity has blossomed into cordiality, we often feel at ease to use terms that might otherwise be disparaging. In this case, it's less about the words used, and more about the already-established relationships. You'd have to ask your friend if he meant to be insulting or genial, but I'd bet on the latter.